# Where did this iCloud profile avatar come from?

Tags: icloud

I created an iCloud account for my daughter, and her profile has an avatar assigned to it that I didn’t choose:
[image]

I think it’s Stitch from the Disney film *Lilo and Stitch* and appears in my daughter’s contact record and in the family iCloud settings. The picture has been on the account since the moment I created it, and my daughter does not currently know of the existence of this account (or currently have any iOS devices), so can not have uploaded it herself.

Was this automatically selected by Apple? I created an account for my son last year and it didn’t have an avatar, and neither does my own, so I was wondering if this could have been picked up from another service she has a profile on (although I checked Gravatar and she doesn’t have one on there).

Comment: look to your left or right, the reason is standing right next to you :) or...tell us what "other service" did you check.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I haven’t checked any. What I mean is, if you have a profile picture on Google for example, that appears in your contact record when I add your details to my phone. There are services like Gravatar (which I’ve already checked as I said) that set your avatar on all different accounts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I asked her (without giving away why) if she’s used this as a profile picture elsewhere and she told me it’s the pic on her YouTube profile. I added her Google  email address as a secondary email (for account recovery) when I created her iCloud account, so Apple must have scraped her Google account for a profile picture.

Answer (score 4):

The person signed in to iCloud can upload any image they choose and no avatar is chosen by Apple. On macOS there are some generic account photos so your question makes great sense, but iCloud has no such stock content supplied.

To date, everything is a digital file that someone uploads from the photos app or loaded with intention in to the iCloud control apps (settings / system preferences) or web site.

Tell your daughter she has good taste and I’ll encourage you and your son to start having fun with art or photos that reduce to a set of pixels.

Comment: Ah wait, I should have specified; my daughter did not do this. She doesn’t even know she has an iCloud account (phone is a Christmas present). Will edit my Q.

Comment: @Darren Don't forget - if anyone can walk up to any device that your daughter was signed in to, they are a proxy for your daughter. Unless you lock every device, all the time - you could have someone open your twitter or facebook and post "poopin" - there are rules to this game, after all. Perhaps your daughter has friends that made a nicer version of that game? http://poopinrules.com

Comment: your comment doesn’t even make sense. What game? As I said, she can’t have been signed in with this account anywhere as she doesn’t even know it exists. The only device this account has been used on is an iPhone that is currently hidden under my bed.

Comment: Here's the thing @Darren. Someone added that icon. I believed it was your daughter, but it could have been anyone. a) someone else knows her account and password b) someone else had access to a device already signed in c) she did it. You would need video surveillance to know for sure and possibly Apple to tell you the date/time when it was set if you don't know it. This site is more about "how the software functions" than "who done it" so hopefully you can take my answer for "how Apple designed this".

Comment: No - I clearly have no idea how to answer questions here. Look for someone else to help, please.

Comment: I feel like you’re having trouble understanding the following points: the profile had that picture from THE SECOND I created it. No one else knows the account even exists. It has only ever been signed in from one device, which is currently switched off and under my bed. Another person did not do this. Anyway, I answered my question myself and have posted an answer.

Comment: I understand that's your clear belief of the situation. I'm also happy if you don't like any or all of my answer. If it helps others and someone else gets you the answer you select - I'll be happy for us both. Sorry I'm not getting you the words you hoped to hear.

Comment: sorry, I hit submit on my comet before I finished typing it and have reworded it to be less harsh.